# Getting rid of space between Buttons in Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-button

I am unable to reduce spacing between my 2 buttons in linear layout .
I tried many combinations , but not successful.

Here is my XML snippet :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/linSocial">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook"
        android:id="@+id/btFacebook"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gmaillogo"
        android:id="@+id/btGmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you check this line `android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"`? it might be the space you are talking about.

Comment: Hey , thanks for your input . Though something else solved the issue .android:layout_marginTop="-60dp" in seccond button :D

Comment: Make sure your `btFacebook` has not internal spacing.

Comment: What combinations did you try exactly? And can you post a screenshot of what the current layout looks like and explain what you want to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linSocial">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook"
    android:id="@+id/btFacebook"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gmaillogo"
    android:id="@+id/btGmail"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```